# Can I select text in grid control and put a cursor to highlight it?

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a devexpress grid control. I have a search functionality written by myself to find out the matched row cell value by looking the selected value in each row cell (though grid control has its own incremental search function, I don't want to use that because that requires a focus on a column and a click on the column.)

Now I have the row cell value AAB, I am searching AA, and I hope when I type the first "A", there is a highlight on the first "A" of "AAB" and I wish a cursor appears behind the first "A"; Then I type the second "A", I hope "AA" of "AAB" is highlighted and the cursor shifts to the right of "AA"...

Can I do such in devexpress grid control? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported in gridControl right now, but you can get more information about this and can try to implementing it using these following links:
[Incremental Search on All Columns](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q240655.aspx)
[Searching a grid (column) without filtering](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q304520.aspx)
[Incremental search based upon group row texts](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B35402.aspx)